# to display arraylist in list view

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

The code is changed according to this [example](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429).
The relevant files are specified below.
I am not using the imageicon part of that example because I don't need it.

**Pending.java**

```
public class Pending {

public String title;
public Pending(){
    super();
}

public Pending(String title) {
    super();

    this.title = title;
}

}
```

**PendingAdatapter.java**

```
public PendingAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Pending[] data) {

    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
   PendingHolder holder = null;

   if(row == null)
   {
       LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
       row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

       holder = new PendingHolder();

       holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

       row.setTag(holder);
   }
   else
   {
       holder = (PendingHolder)row.getTag();
   }

   Pending weather = data[position];
   holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);

   return row;

}

static class PendingHolder
{

    TextView txtTitle;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
WayDataBase way1=new WayDataBase(Dashboard.this);
    Pending weather_data[] = new Pending[]
            {

                new Pending(way1.returnFormName().toString())
            };

    PendingAdapter adapter = new PendingAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);
    lstvw=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.forms_list);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    lstvw.addHeaderView(header);

    lstvw.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the **returnFormname function of the database**

```
public ArrayList<String> returnFormName()
{

    openOrCreateDatabase();
    createlandtTable();
    createrefertable();
    createassettable();
    createofficeusetable();
    ArrayList<String> form = new ArrayList<String>();

    int appcount=0,refercount=0,assetcount=0,officecount=0;
    appcount=db.rawQuery("select * from "+TableNameis+";" ,null).getCount();
    refercount=db.rawQuery("select * from "+ReferenceTable+";" ,null).getCount();
    assetcount=db.rawQuery("select * from "+AssetTable+";" ,null).getCount();
    officecount=db.rawQuery("select * from "+OfficeUse+";" ,null).getCount();
    if(appcount==0)
    {
        form.add("Applicant");
    }
    if(refercount==0)
    {
        form.add("Reference");
    }
    if(assetcount==0)
    {
        form.add("Asset Details");
    }
    if(officecount==0)
    {
        form.add("Office Use");
    }

    return form;
}
```

Comment: you should implement custom data adapter that extends from BaseAdapter and ofcourse custom view for it

Comment: create custom adapter http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: @VirtualVoid i am really new to android coding..i have no idea what your saying..could you provide me some example or any sample code snippet for reference??

Comment: I think problem is in your  formname.add(way1.returnFormName().toString());
So just try to debug it.Print "way1.returnFormName().toString()" into Logcat and see what it returns.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy the values in my app are cumin from the database so m not sure how many values will be there...your example specifies the no.of values..will this be applicable in my app??

Comment: No need to specify no of values just it's an example. custom means create as like as you want. get all the values from DB and then store in ArrayList<String> pass them to adapter. try coding like this. and let me know if you get any problems i will help.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy i used that code it is only displaying header the list items are not to seen

Comment: show the code what you tried, edit your answer with relevant code what your using now.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy i have edited my question please see and let me know what am i missing here.

Comment: ok what you want to achieve now, i mean how to show in listview item.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy yes..as you can see the arraylist is coming from the database.. i want to display those values in a list view one below the other

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line `formname.add(way1.returnFormName().toString());`. I don't know what `WayDataBase` returns, but what you want to do is add each value in `way1` to `formname`. What you did is returned a single representation of the object `way1.returnFormName()` in String form, that is what `toString()` does.

Take each value from `way1.returnFormName()` and add it to `formname` by itself.

Note: to convert an `int` or `double` to a `String`, just concatenate an empty String to it. Ex.

```
int number = 5;
String some;
some = number +"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

**MainActivity.java**

```
WayDataBase way1=new WayDataBase(Dashboard.this);
ArrayList<String> weather_data = way1.returnFormName();    

PendingAdapter adapter = new PendingAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);
lstvw=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.forms_list);

View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
lstvw.addHeaderView(header);

lstvw.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**PendingAdatapter.java**

```
public PendingAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View row = convertView;
   PendingHolder holder = null;

   if(row == null)
   {
      LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
      row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

      holder = new PendingHolder();

      holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

      row.setTag(holder);
   }
   else
   {
      holder = (PendingHolder)row.getTag();
   }

   holder.txtTitle.setText(data.get(position));
   return row;
}
```

Comment: `super(context, layoutResourceId,data);`  this line in the code is showing error as `The constructor ArrayAdapter<Pending>(Context, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined` how do i rectify it?

Comment: change your adapter extension with ArrayAdapter<String>

Comment: yes the error is gone but still m not able to display anything.

Comment: First show your `listview_item_row` and then check your data have values or not.

Comment: sorry i dint get you. what exactly am i supposed to do?